# I want to convert a number to time in R

Tags: r

say I have a number 1234, and I need to convert that to 12:34 i.e 12:34pm and eventually convert that to minutes in the day starting from 0000.

Comment: `as.numeric(substring(as.character(1234), 1, 2))*60 + as.numeric(substring(as.character(1234), 3, 4))`

Comment: We're going to need some more examples to get this right for you - how is 8:30am going to be represented in your numbers?

Comment: `as.integer(difftime(as.POSIXct(as.character(1234), format = '%H%M'), as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), '00:00:00')), units = 'mins'))`

Answer (score 3):

A bit of integer division and modulo should work:

```
x <- c(1234,830)
(x %/% 100) * 60 + x %% 100
#[1] 754 510
```

If you absolutely need a time representation first:

```
tmp <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04d", x), format="%H%M")
tmp - trunc(tmp, "day")
#Time differences in mins
#[1] 754 510
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `sub` and `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
times(sub("(.{2})", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d:00", x)))
#[1] 12:34:00 08:30:00
```

---

If we need to convert to 'minute' then

```
library(lubridate)
minute(as.period(hms(sub("(.{2})", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d:00", x))), unit = "minute"))
#[1] 754 510
```

#### data

```
x <- c(1234,830)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(x = "1234", format = "%H%M", tz = "UTC")
minutes(x) + hour(x) * 60
```

Result:

```
[1] 754
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time integer is based on a 24 hour format (which should be otherwise you can't distinguish between am and pm):

```
time <- 1234
time_converted <- sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", time) 
> time_converted
[1] "12:34"
minutes <- as.POSIXlt(time_converted, format="%H:%M")$hour *60 + as.POSIXlt(time_converted, format="%H:%M")$min
> minutes
[1] 754
```